# Visual Basic- Runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime

The Visual Basic code below is made to take into account new (last) columns in all the graphs of my Excel Spreadsheets. It was functioning during 4 months without any issue and now without changing anything, it doesn’t function anymore and I have the “Runtime error 1004” on following line :

**Rinitemp = workgraph.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).FormulaLocal**

I’ve been looking on forums for this error but each time, it seems to be for a very different reason. After several weeks of search, could someone help me ?
Complete code is :

```
Sub Add_col()

    Dim Cible As ChartObject

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Dim Rinit, Rfinale As String

    Dim Rinitemp As String

    Dim FinPlageInit, FinPlageFinale As String

    FinPlageInit = "$BD"

    FinPlageFinale = "$BE"


    For Each Wb In Workbooks

        For Each ws In Wb.Worksheets

            For Each workgraph In ws.ChartObjects

                'For all series

                For j = 1 To workgraph.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

                       Rinitemp = workgraph.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).FormulaLocal
                       Position_chaine_A_remplacer = InStr(Rinitemp, FinPlageInit)
                       LongueurChaine = Len(Rinitemp)
                       While Position_chaine_A_remplacer > 0
                           Rfinale = Mid(Rinitemp, 1, Position_chaine_A_remplacer - 1) _
                           & FinPlageFinale _
                           & Mid(Rinitemp, Position_chaine_A_remplacer + 3, LongueurChaine)
                           Rinitemp = Rfinale
                          Position_chaine_A_remplacer = InStr(Position_chaine_A_remplacer + 1, Rfinale,   FinPlageInit)
                          workgraph.Chart.SeriesCollection(j).FormulaLocal = Rfinale
                        Wend                  
                Next j
           Next workgraph
      Next ws
   Next Wb
End Sub
```

Comment: I was getting the same 1004 error in debug mode on something that had been working just fine earlier.  I fixed it by activating the worksheet. Try putting `ws.Activate` right after  `For Each ws In Wb.Worksheets`.

Comment: Thank you. I still have the same runtime error after putting ws.Activate.  In fact, I was almost sure that the sheet was activated as before I tried to put message box(MsgBox) to display FormulaLocal values.

Comment: It's pretty antagonizing. I took your code and ran it in one of my workbooks and it ran without error.  I'm not sure what is causing the 1004 error.

Comment: What seems to be crazy is that there is no error for "first" FormulaLocal values.